# Combinatorics - Seating arrangement problem

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

9 girls are to be seated in a row.  Of the 9 girls, 6 insist on being seated in consecutive positions.  And of these 6, further 3 girls insist on being seated adjacent to each other.  In how many distinct ways can the 9 girls be seated ?

---

**My Attempt :-**

Ways of selecting 6 girls out of 9 who want to sit together = $\binom{9}{6}$

Now out of these 6 girls selected we have to further select 3 girls who want to sit adjacent to each other which would be possible in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways

Now for the arrangement purposes, I did:-  $4! \cdot 4! \cdot 3!$

$4!$ ways in which the block of 6 girls and 3 separate girls can be arranged

another $4!$ ways in which the block of 3 girls and 3 separate girls in the 6 selected girls can be arranged

and finally $3!$ ways in which the three adjacent sitting girls can be arranged

which gives my final result as   $\binom{9}{6}\binom{6}{3} \cdot 4! \cdot 4! \cdot 3!$ ways

Please guide me where am I going wrong, and what would be the correct method?

Comment: The girls know who want to sit together, they didn’t ask you to choose who want to sit together

Comment: Work backwards.  Suppose that you have $~6~$ girls, $~3~$ of which must be adjacent.  Considering the adjacent girls as one fused unit that permits $~3!~$ internal permutations, the enumeration is $~4! \times 3!.~$  To complete the problem, consider that the $~6~$ girls form 1 fused unit, so an additional factor of $~4!~$ is needed.  So, the overall computation is $$4! \times 4! \times 3!.$$

Comment: Note that your calculation gives a result that is larger than 9!, the number of ways the girls could sit without restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The girls who want to sit together are some particular girls. For example number the girls 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. Let the six girls who insist on sitting in consecutive positions be 1,2,3,4,5,6 and among them let 1,2,3 be the girls who again want to be seated adjacent to each other. So these are already fixed. You shouldn't select them explicitly. Hence the remaining computation
4! x 4! x 3! is the answer.